# Can I supress OpenCV / cv2 warnings in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, warnings

Whenever I try the command `cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)`, I get the following warning

```
[ WARN:0@858.663] global /private/var/folders/k1/30mswbxs7r1g6zwn8y4fyt500000gp/T/abs_11nitadzeg/croot/opencv-suite_1691620374638/work/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2386) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin
```

And 3, almost, identical ones. The entire warning from just the single line of code VideoCapture (with an import above it of course) is

```
[ WARN:0@270.964] global /private/var/folders/k1/30mswbxs7r1g6zwn8y4fyt500000gp/T/abs_11nitadzeg/croot/opencv-suite_1691620374638/work/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2386) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin
[ WARN:0@270.964] global /private/var/folders/k1/30mswbxs7r1g6zwn8y4fyt500000gp/T/abs_11nitadzeg/croot/opencv-suite_1691620374638/work/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2402) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module uridecodebin1 reported: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
[ WARN:0@270.964] global /private/var/folders/k1/30mswbxs7r1g6zwn8y4fyt500000gp/T/abs_11nitadzeg/croot/opencv-suite_1691620374638/work/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@270.964] global /private/var/folders/k1/30mswbxs7r1g6zwn8y4fyt500000gp/T/abs_11nitadzeg/croot/opencv-suite_1691620374638/work/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

Now, this is very annying since I need to use the VideoCapture command multiple times. The warnings get even worse when trying the tp.batch command on the video (import trackpy as tp).

Is there any way to stop all of these warnings?

I've tried the following:

`os.environ["OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL"] = "SILENT"` , `tp.quiet()`, `os.environ["OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL"] = "FATAL"` and `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore').` None have helped.